# Django thinks I have an id field when I do not

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

I have created the following model:

```
class World(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    setting = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
```

when I run `manage.py makemigrations` I get the following error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to world without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

Why does Django think I have an id field, and how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: *If you don’t specify primary_key=True for any fields in your model, Django will automatically add an IntegerField to hold the primary key, so you don’t need to set primary_key=True on any of your fields unless you want to override the default primary-key behavior. For more, see [Automatic primary key fields.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)*

Comment: If you do not define a primary key yourself, Django automatically adds an `id` field. Did you, by any chance, earlier defined a primary key yourself for this `World` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did but I have since run manage.py flush and manage.py sqlflush which should have removed any of that to start from scratch?

Comment: @GPPK: yes, but a migration is not aware of the data *in* the database, so it assumes (this is not strange, since migrations can be applied to any database), that there can be records, and thus it needs to inject values for these.

Comment: @GPPK: `flush` doesn't remove any tables. `sqlflush` doesn't do anything to the database, that just prints what `flush` would execute.

Comment: I added the new ID field, and pressed yes that I had renamed it, this has fixed the issue. Thanks for your help @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0):

I had previously set an ID field in my World model, this was confusing something as I had deleted it, I have added the line:

`id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

When i ran makemitigrations again it asked me if I had renamed the ID field to this new one and I clicked yes and this sorted it out.

My model is now:

```
class World(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    setting = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
```